# androidx - Implement androidx Preferences in an Activity (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, preference

**What's the objective**

Im currently working on an app, which has a settings screen, containing a recyclerview. This recyclerview, on item click, opens the relative activity, which are the Settings' submenus (Code below). In the newly opened activity, i want to implement using the implementation `androidx.prefrence` a preference screen.

**What's the problem**

For this, im following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PS9jhuHECEQ). In this video, they set up a preference screen using `PreferenceFragmentCompact`. The problem with this, is the fact that we are setting up a new activity and then a new fragment, which in my app its not efficient, since im building my settings with just activities.

**Considering this, is it possible to setup a Preference screen in an activity without using fragments? If so, how?**

**Code:**

```
class ActivitySettings : AppCompatActivity(), AdapterSettings.OnItemClickListener {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)

        topToolbarBack.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }

        val settingsList = listOf(
            DataItemsSettings(getString(R.string.look), getString(R.string.lookdescription), R.drawable.ic_colored_color_lens),
            DataItemsSettings(getString(R.string.playing), getString(R.string.playingdescription), R.drawable.ic_colored_view_carousel),
            DataItemsSettings(getString(R.string.images), getString(R.string.imagesdscription), R.drawable.ic_colored_image),
            DataItemsSettings(getString(R.string.audio), getString(R.string.audiodescription), R.drawable.ic_colored_volume_up),
            DataItemsSettings(getString(R.string.other), getString(R.string.otherdescription), R.drawable.ic_colored_shape),
            DataItemsSettings(getString(R.string.about), getString(R.string.aboutdescription), R.drawable.ic_colored_info)
        )

        val adapter = AdapterSettings(settingsList, this)
        rvSettings.adapter = adapter
        rvSettings.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    }

    override fun OnItemClick(position: Int) {
        when(position) {
            0 -> this.startActivity(Intent(this, ActivitySettingsLook::class.java))
            1 -> this.startActivity(Intent(this, ActivitySettingsPlaying::class.java))
            2 -> this.startActivity(Intent(this, ActivitySettingsImages::class.java))
            3 -> this.startActivity(Intent(this, ActivitySettingsAudio::class.java))
            4 -> this.startActivity(Intent(this, ActivitySettingsOther::class.java))
            5 -> this.startActivity(Intent(this, ActivityAbout::class.java))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The androidx Preferences are only designed for use through a PreferenceFragmentCompat. Android also has non-androidx built-in preferences that can be used in a PreferenceActivity, but this is all deprecated and kind of out of date. I would not worry about using PreferenceFragmentCompat. It is a trivial amount of overhead to have an Activity with a single Fragment. You could make all your settings screens use the sae Activity class and load a different PreferenceFragment based on some intend extra you pass, just so you don't need quite as much code duplication.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks for your reply. I thought that having single Activities with a single Fragment would be less efficient in size and speed. Im new to Android so i wanted to choose an easy way to implement without causing mess in the Project folder. I will rework the settings screen so i can make it more efficent and cleaner using fragments.